# Doubt on the meaning/notation of definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, notation

This is perhaps a stupid question, but I was wondering about this: suppose we have a function $f(x)$ continuous on some interval.

The question is: when we write

$$\int_0^1 f(x)\ \text{d}x$$

we treat the interval of integration as $(0, 1)$ or as $[0, 1]$?
Is there any difference in this sense? Are there any notations? Like, say, something as

$$\int_{0 + \tau}^{1 - \tau} f(x)\ \text{d}x$$

as $\tau \to 0$ when the interval is $(0, 1)$?

Comment: It can matter in some cases taking the limit, but integrals are generally agnostic of the value of a function at any one point.

Comment: @Manifoldski Yes, thank you!